# FFmpeg avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_OPUS) and avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_OPUS) both return NULL

Tags: ffmpeg

The FFmpeg I am using is fine, because it works if I use AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_U8 and some the other CODEC with avcodec_find_encoder and avcodec_find_decoder.

Anybody knows why the finder coder functions always return NULL with AV_CODEC_ID_OPUS?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check three things:

- Is your `fmpeg` compiled with opus decodec? What does `ffmpeg -decoders | grep libopus` say?
- Do you call `av_register_all`?
- Is libopus present on your machine, and is it the same version ffmpeg expects (I'd try strace/ltrace)?

libopus is not compiled in by default:

```
ffmpeg-2.1.3> ./configure --help | grep opus
  --enable-libopus         enable Opus decoding via libopus [no]
```

so you need to specify `--enable-libopus` (and of course have libopus in your toolchain)

Comment: Everything is OK if I use the pre-built version downloaded from official website. This problem happens if I use my own version built with options:
 
./configure --toolchain=msvc --enable-shared --disable-optimizations --enable-debug=3 --enable-small --extra-cflags="-l/c/MinGW"

Comment: I've updated my answer; libopus is not enabled by default, you need to explicitly enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Once your ffmpeg lib has `--enable-libopus` you may also use
`avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("libopus")` and `avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libopus")`